# The update nor the destroy methods won't work in laravel eloquent model?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent, model

I have a strange situation where eloquent model won't let me update nor destroy while index and create is working fine!

I'm using Vue.js and Laravel API Resource for form control, and while it worked with me before, it won't work here:

Here's my Vue.js Code:

```
updateFinish(finish) {
    axios.patch(`/api/finishes/${finish.id}`, finish).then(response => { 
        this.fetchFinishes();
    }).catch(error => {
      // Get laravel validation error
      this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
   });
},
```

laravel update code (not working)

```php
public function update(FinishType $finishType)
    {
        // Don't know why not working
        $finishType->update($this->validateRequest());
        return new FinishTypeResource($finishType);
    }
```

the response is `null`:
`{"id":null,"name":null}`

While this code works:

```php
public function update($id)
    {
        $finishType = FinishType::find($id);
        $validates = $this->validateRequest();
        $finishType->name = $validates['name'];
        $finishType->save();
        return new FinishTypeResource($finishType);
    }

public function validateRequest()
    {
        return request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required | unique:finish_types',
        ]);
    }
```

Note the Model name is `FinishType` and database table name is `finish_types`, I even tried to define the table name in the model like so `protected $table = 'finish_types'` – still not working and I already have defined the `$fillable` array!!!

Comment: Please show the code for `validateRequest()` function, I didn't find it in the laravel source code.

Comment: Yes sorry, i did edit the post to include the `validateRequest()` function...the thing is i have that same exact code for other models and it's working find!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route model binding is not working correctly, for the *implicit binding* to work your `injected variable` should match the `route parameter name`.

Assuming that your parameter name could be `finish` (reading the url from your javascript) you have to write the update function using `$finish` as injected variable, like this:

```php
public function update(FinishType $finish)
{
    $finish->update($this->validateRequest());
    return new FinishTypeResource($finish);
}
```

Do the same for destroy():

```php
public function destroy(FinishType $finish)
{
     // your destroy code here
}
```

In any case you can run `php artisan route:list` to find your `parameter name` (the part of the URI in braces) and give the *same name* to the `injected variable`.

If the two do not match, parameter and injected variable name, laravel injects a **void**, not loaded, `FinishType` model so it does not make sense doing an update or a delete on it.

Comment: Here's my API Routes

`// Finishes API`
`Route::get('/finishes', 'FinishTypeController@index');`
`Route::post('/finishes', 'FinishTypeController@store');`
`Route::patch('/finishes/{finish}', 'FinishTypeController@update');`
`Route::delete('/finishes/{finish}', 'FinishTypeController@destroy');`

Comment: So my answer is valid: you have to use `$finish` as injected variable because you used `{finish}` as the parameter name

Comment: Well i did rename the routing to this and it worked fine thank you
`Route::patch('/finishtypes/{finishType}', 'FinishTypeController@update');`

Answer (score 0):

I can't post comments so I'm going to post what I assume is the answer.

Laravel does route model binding automagically when the route url name corresponds to the name of the table I think... or model.

So `users/{id}` would auto bind the User object when you type it as a param in the controller. Example `(User $user)`

However, since your URL seems to be "different" from the name of your Model/Table, go to the RouteServiceProvider, and manually do the binding.

So in your case you'd do something like this in the boot function of the RouteServiceProvider class:

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('finishes', FinishType::class);
}
```

Don't forget your imports :)

You can read more about Explicit Model Binding here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#explicit-binding

Comment: Here's my API Routes

`// Finishes API`
`Route::get('/finishes', 'FinishTypeController@index');`
`Route::post('/finishes', 'FinishTypeController@store');`
`Route::patch('/finishes/{finish}', 'FinishTypeController@update');`
`Route::delete('/finishes/{finish}', 'FinishTypeController@destroy');`

Comment: Yes. You need to specify the binding in the RouteServiceProvider file because `finishes` wont auto-bind `FinishType::class`... your issue would be resolved either by manually doing the one line bind like i specified above, or switching your urls to `/finishTypes/`

Comment: @Keroles Do what I mentioned above. Find the RouteServiceProvider file and add the line `Route::model('finishes', FinishType::class);` to the boot method. Don't forget to add the import for the FinishType model at the top of the class.

Comment: Well i did rename the routing to this and it worked fine thank you
`Route::patch('/finishtypes/{finishType}', 'FinishTypeController@update');`